# Using Angular Material with Angular Formly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-formly

I'm building an **Angular2/4** app with **Angular Formly** (https://github.com/formly-js/ng-formly) and don't know how to give it an **Angular Material** (https://github.com/angular/material2) look.

With the **AngularJS** + **angular-formly** (http://angular-formly.com) + **AngularJS Material** trio it used to work as seen in the formly docs (http://angular-formly.com/#!/example/integrations/angular-material):

```
var app = angular.module('formlyExample', ['formly', 'ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial']);
```

But how does this look like using Angular2 and the corresponding version of formly?

(I have material2 installed and all its necessary component modules imported.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to install formly-material template separately.

```
npm install @ngx-formly/material --save
```

> Just follow all the steps specified [here](https://formly-js.github.io/ngx-formly/guide/getting-started), notice step 2 and it will work.